# How to remove strings at left of "-" in filename in TYPO3 Fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, viewhelper

Using TYPO3 8 LTS, we got many standardized filenames like:

```
ABC_105-Report.pdf 
DEFGH_110-Brochure.ppt
```

We need to remove whatever is at left of "-" so it becomes a list like this in TYPO3 Frontend:

```
Report.pdf 
Brochure.ppt
```

We are already using VHS Viewhelpers which contains Format:Eliminiate, Substring so it may be part of the solution.

Comment: Can you please put your current code for generating list?

Comment: You can use split in TypoScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is VHS: Format / PregReplaceViewHelper.

```
<f:alias map="{filenames: {
    0: 'ABC_105-Report.pdf',
    1: 'DEFGH_110-Brochure.ppt',
    2: 'FilenameWithoutMagicChar.jpg',
    3: 'Multiple-Magic-Chars.jpg'}}">
    <ul>
        <f:for each="{filenames}" as="filename">
            <li>
                {v:format.pregReplace(
                    subject: filename, 
                    pattern: '/^[^-]*-/', 
                    replacement: ''
                )}
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:alias>
```

Result:

- Report.pdf
- Brochure.ppt
- FilenameWithoutMagicChar.jpg
- Magic-Chars.jpg

If '*Chars.jpg*' is required instead of '*Magic-Chars.jpg*', the regular expression is `/-.*/`.

Answer (score 1):

a very basic typoscript viewhelper:

in fluid:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.filenameStub" data="{filename}" />
```

in typoscript:

```
lib.filenameStub = TEXT
lib.filenameStub {
    current = 1
    split {
        max = 2
        token = -
        returnKey = 1
    }
}
```